# Start animating a UIProgressView with a tag?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiprogressview

```
downPreView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
downPreView.tag = indexPath;
downPreView.frame = CGRectMake(75,28, 215,60);
downPreView.progress = 0.0;
[cell.contentView addSubview:downPreView];
```

Now how do I start animating `downPreView` with a tag of `2`, etc?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab a view with the `viewWithTag` method. Like `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]`

**Update**

First of all. You cant animate a progressView, you can show it, hide it, and you can edit it's progress level. If you want to edit it's progress, you have to set it like `[downPreView setProgress:0.1]`. If it's set to 1 the progrees indicator will be at the end.
However if you want just a spinner, you can use `UIActivityIndicatorView`.
If you cant get the cell, then you can use it's parent view. Like `[self.view viewWithTag:1]`
After this you have to cast `UIProgressView` on it to avoid warnings.

```
UIProgressView *progressView = (UIProgressView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
progressView.progress = 0.1;
```

For more info about `UIActivityIndicatorView` please see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006830).

Comment: But how do you start animating it (or change it at least).

Comment: @phpnerd: Try this:  `[[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1] startAnimating];`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However the method I am calling it from is just a plan VOID (`startUploads`), not a tableView method where I can get a cell.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an object by it's tag, you have to retain the object if you want access. Say if you have an array of progress views... you can enumerate it and ask

```
if (object.tag == tagWanted) {
doSomething;
}
```

Comment: `downPreView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
downPreView.tag = 0;
downPreView.frame = CGRectMake(75,28, 215,60);
downPreView.progress = 0.0;
[cell.contentView addSubview:downPreView];` AND `if (downPreView.tag == 0) {
downPreView.progress = 0.15;
}` did nothing.